If $E-E$ contains an interval centered at 0, is $E$ necessarily measurable?
It is a fairly standard problem in Real Analysis (see, for example, Excercise 31 in Ch1 of Folland) to prove that if $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue measurable set such that $m(E) > 0$, then $E-E := \{ x - y : x, y \in E\}$ contains an interval centered at $0$. One possible proof (as hinted in Folland) is take an interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $m(E \cap I) > \frac{3}{4} m(I)$ (which always exists by a previous excercise) and show that $(-\frac{1}{2} m(I), \frac{1}{2} m(I)) \subset E - E$. This shows that although positive measure sets may not necessarily contain an interval (for example, the Fat Cantor Set), their set of differences must.
However, does this characterize measurable sets? For example if we consider the Vitali Set $V \subset [0,1]$, no two elements $x, y \in V$ can differ by a rational and thus $V-V$ cannot contain any interval (this is another way to prove $V$ is not measurable! since for every $q_k \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ if we define $V_k := \{ x + q_k : x \in V\}$ then we have $[0,1] \subseteq \bigcup V_k$ and so at least one $m(V_n) > 0$ but $m(V) = m(V_n)$ so $V$ has positive measure, a contradiction). So, I am curious as to whether or not $E-E$ containing an interval centered at 0 implies that it is measurable. I do not know whether there is a non-measurable set whose set of differences contains an interval (I tried the Bernstein set, however it seems difficult to talk about its set of differences).
On the other hand, if one assumes $E$ is measurable, this does not characterize having positive measure as the cantor set $C \subset [0,1]$ is a measure $0$ set with $C-C = [-1,1]$. Thus, the only converse to consider is
$$ \exists I \subset \mathbb{R} \text{ an interval around 0 with } E - E \supset I \implies E \text{ measurable}.$$
Either a counterexample or a proof of this implication would be enlightening.

$E = [0, 1] \cup F$ where $F$ is a non-measurable subset of $[1, 2]$ is a counterexample.

In general, any non-measurable set that contains a subset that is measurable and of positive measure will work.

The interesting question is whether there is a nonmeasurable set, each of whose measurable subsets is null, whose self-difference contains an interval centered at zero ...

@NoahSchweber Take a Vitali set $V \subset [0, 1]$. Let $C$ be the Cantor set. Then $V \cup (C + 2)$ works.

Sorry, "null" should be "whose self-difference doesn't contain an interval centered on zero." I was sloppy.

@NoahSchweber Ah, yeah, that’s a hard question. I would guess yes. Maybe some kind of transfinite induction construction would work…? I don’t immediately see how to do it, though.

oh, oops... i guess this isn't a very interesting question then. Thanks for answering though!
